# Can a ransomware in a VMware break out?

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware, virus

I want to test some Ransomware. Therefore I wanna use VMware and create a virtual machine, where I can execute this software. I already deleted the Network device, so that no connection is possible between my computer and the VM. Do I need to know something more about it. Could it be possible that the virus breaks out and affects my PC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you are not playing around with Cerber 6 Ransomware because it has Anti-VM features that can easily bluff you when you are on the test. I just got to know the same from this post:http://ransomwares.net/cerber-6-ransomware/. I request you to read this post to know more about Cerber's new Anti-VM & Anti-Sandboxing features which makes it dangerous than never before!

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to disable all shared folders. Also disable any CPU virtualisation acceleration, then you should be fine.